# how does scala expression results in string consisting elements of array

Tags: scala

I was going through Chapter 10(Composition and Inheritance) from "Programming in Scala" and can some one explain how this expression is constructed and how does it work?

```
def toString = contents mkString "\n"
```

The author has the code listing as follows:

```
abstract class Element{
  def contents:Array[String]
  def width: Int = if(height==0)0elsecontents(0).length
  def height: Int = contents.length
  def above(that: Element): Element =
      new ArrayElement(this.contents ++ that.contents)
  def beside(that: Element): Element=
              new ArrayElement(
                 for(
                   (line1, line2)<-this.contents zip that.contents
                ) yield line1+line2
              )
  override def toString = contents mkString "\n"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [mkString](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/#scala.Array) documentation for Array. Basically it will call `toString` on every element of `contents` and then it will print separator in between neighboring pairs of elements. In your case the separator is a newline, so result of that is going to be a string with every element of `contents` in a separate line.

Comment: getting to some basics that I missed. It is essentially a way of invoking a method in scala. Here is nice documentation  http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html